# Power BI Server connection to Azure Boards

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server, azure-boards

I've been making some Power BI (PBI) dashboards with data I have extracted from Azure DevOps Boards (Boards) using PBI's Desktop built connector.
Everything works fine on the desktop application and on the Power BI Web Service.

The Problem:
After moving the PBI file to the PBI local hosted server I can not call the data to be auto refreshed. This is because the same Boards connector is not available for PBI server as is for PBI desktop and web service.

Attempts at a solution:
I have tried to create an API call to get all of the fields from ADO but at the moment I can only call from one work item at a time.
I'm currently looking at calling a query in ADO to produce an excel file that can be placed on the PBI server, but I don't know how to continuously cache data..

Does anyone have any idea if it is possible to add the boards connector or how to accumulate the cached data in a PBI file?

Comment: Have you checked if Azure Devops connector can be used for PBI server? See [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/create-quick-report?view=azure-devops) for more information. You can also use OData Query to create PBI report. Check out [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/create-quick-report-odataq?view=azure-devops)